# User card Overflow / Underflow ™ on non-English sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, localization, user-card

On [this question on Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189320/extraer-elementos-de-un-data-frame-en-r), the text on the user cards for both the author and the last editor cause an overflow/underflow:

[image]

Comment: Weird; it looks like Jorgesys is a mod on Meta.SE now! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've deployed a fix for this that wraps any dates that are longer than the user cards. The user card on the post you linked now looks like this:

[image: A screenshot of the date in the user card that is truncated. It says "formulada el 16 ago. 2018 a las 16:33"]

Comment: Safe to change the tag to status-completed, then? (Also, will this or another method work to see the full date on mobile?)

Comment: @V2Blast That's an important point. AFAICT, there's no way for this to work on mobile (at least on Chrome for Android).

Comment: @V2Blast another method would be to use the revision history or the timeline.

Comment: Why not remove the 'at' and its translations all together. That would save a lot of space on those cards.

Comment: @V2Blast Oh yes, this is totally hiding information on mobile. We'll take a second pass on this and get it to wrap instead. I'll update this answer when it's done!

Comment: @Luuklag I'll look into translation options too. I expect that this translation is used in multiple contexts across the site and so I wouldn't want to change it everywhere. Maybe we could provide another kind of translation string for a shorter relative date?  Not yet committing to a solution there though

Comment: Actually it looks like SOpt is already doing a shorter date format, so this should be possible for us to change

Comment: We've fixed this so it wraps instead of truncating - thanks for the feedback 